# Change Database of existing Database Connection - Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5

I recently got to know about the Laravel Framework which is awesome but just want to know one query which is still a mystery for me.

I know we can easily **change the "Database Connection"** using

```
      $users = DB::connection('mysql2')->select(...);
```

but I'm working on such a project where **Multiple Databases are created as per user request and need to access these databases dynamically as per user request**.

Its nearly **impossible** to enter every database entry as new database connection entry in Database config file.

***Hence I need a way to change the Database dynamically in the same connection we are using.***

eg.

If we are using **"DB1" connection** with **Database "test1"** as defined in config file,

I need a way to change the "test1" database to "test2" **DYNAMICALLY**

Comment: Why do you have multiple databases?

Comment: I'm working over single framework for multiple organizations, hence the data for each organization needs to be stored in distinct database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you can do that by simply changing the value of the database configuration at runtime:

```
Config::set('database.connections.DB1.test1', 'test2');
```

Comment: Thanks. That may help though.

Answer (score 1):

You could save database connection(s) for each user in a "central" database. Query that database, find the matching connection parameters and use them to query the user's database.

Multi-tenant applications use a similar approach. I've created a [package](https://github.com/kwalit/multi-tenant) to craft multi-tenant applications with Laravel. This package requires 'tenants' to be defined in a config file... which you do not want. Take a look at the source code tho. It might help you bring up new ideas.